# Splitting dataframe into multiple ones according to proportion of samplesize and labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, dataset

I want to create my training, validation and testset from one dataframe with
a proportion of 6:2:2.

But additionally within each set, I'd like to have a proportion
of 6:4 between the 2 labels. Among the original dataframe this 6:4 proportion is
not given, one label is massively overrepresented.
Maybe I should adjust that in advance?

I think sklearns train_test_split() might be an option but to be honest
its documentation did not make me any wiser...

Are there any best practices for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an imbalanced dataset, you can use the parameter `'stratify'` in the `train_test_split()`. This will make the dataset be split into training and test sets in such a way that the ratio of the class labels in the variable specified is constant i.e. both train and test set will have the same ratio of class labels.